# Obtener edad en base a date en bbdd

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Estimados, 
Quiero guardar una fecha de nacimiento desde formulario con jsp, luego guardarla en bbdd mysql para despues obtenerla desde la bbdd y calcular la edad. Alguna idea de como lograrlo? Saludos.

```
<form action="cPaciente" method="post">
<label style="color:red"><%=msj %></label>
<table width="35%">
 <tr >
  <td><label for="rut">Rut:  </label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ingresoRUT" title="Rut sin guion"         pattern="[0-9]{1,15}" value="<%=Rut %>" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="13%"><label for="nombre">Nombre: </label></td>
  <td width="87%"><input type="text" name="ingresoNombre"></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="apellido">Apellido:  </label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ingresoApellido"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <!-- Aqui se ingresa la fecha de nacimiento -->
  <td><label for="edad">Fecha Nacimiento:  </label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ingresoNacimiento"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: El código que agregaste en tu pregunta no muestra lo que intentas hacer para guardar esa información en tu base de datos. Busca un poco mas en internet. Puedes encontrar por ejemplo esta [ejemplo en esta página](https://coderanch.com/t/290863/java/Save-data-JSP-text-box).

Answer (score 0):

Así: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'1985-09-19',CURDATE()) AS edad`

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un poco más de explicación al respecto?